# Class produces same result everyday using SOQL Today() function

Tags: apex, soql, scheduled-apex, job

I have a class that implements Schedulable...pulls in a list of records created today, by using the `TODAY()` function. The data should change, and when the SOQL query is run manually, I do get different results each day. However, the class produces the same result today (list of records) as it did yesterday.

This in spite of the fact that the query produces different results each day.

Query includes :

```
SELECT ID
       ,Product__r.Name
   FROM Contract 
   WHERE (StartDate = Today)
   AND (Status = 'Activated')
   AND (NOT Dr__r.Name LIKE '%Test Dealer%')
   AND (Dr__r.Is_Test_Account__c = FALSE)
```

Comment: It is good to see you included the query in your post. Just a note, you do not need to wrap each `WHERE` clause in parentheses. Only if you are using `OR` clauses.

Comment: Perhaps include your entire `Schedulable`.

Comment: Are the results different compared to several days ago? Timezones can be in play that make day boundaries move by a few hours. See e.g. [Gotcha: convertTimezone() must be used in SOQL Date functions dealing with Datetime](https://force746.wordpress.com/2013/09/04/gotcha-converttimezone-must-be-used-in-soql-date-functions-dealing-with-datetime/).

Comment: @KeithC I would vote for that as an answer.